# How to make scatter plot points into numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am creating a scatter plot using ggplot/geom_point. Here is my code for building the function in ggplot.

```
AddPoints <- function(x) {
    list(geom_point(data = dat , mapping =  aes(x = x, y = y) , shape = 1 , size = 1.5 ,
color = "blue"))
}
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to replace the standard points on the plot with numbers. That is, instead of seeing a dot on the plot, you would see a number on the plot to represent each observation. I would like that number to correspond to a column for that given observation (column name 'RP'). Thanks in advance.

Sample data.

```
 Data <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
     Y = sample(3:12),
    RP = sample(c(4,8,9,12,3,1,1,2,7,7)))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `geom_text` seems useful here.

Comment: @MrFlick please see updated sample data

Comment: BTW, the function argument is just `x`, but the contents references `dat` and `y` as well. Also, your additional sample data uses upper-case `X` and `Y`, so it isn't clear what is what here. Regardless, I think `geom_text(aes(x=Y, y=Y, label=RP), data=x)` might suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `geom_text()` and map the rp variable to the label argument.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = X, y = Y, label = RP)) +
  geom_text()
```